# 'Jump' Operation in Python to Skip Rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file contain data like in that picture.

[image: DataFrame]

"doc_id" refers to the document ID where the text comes from. In our example, we have 4 documents (doc_id from 0 to 3).

I want to get the values of "text" in the first 5 pages of each document OR before Table of Contents.

With our example, it should return:
"A0","A1","B1","A3"

(Note that we don't want B0, C0, D0, C1 because they occur after Table of Contents of that document, and we don't want A2 and B3 because they have page_id >= 5)

I don't understand how we can create condition to "break" the iteration in each doc_id once we find Table of Contents or page_id == 5 and move to the next doc_id.

I tried like this and I'm stuck.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('book2.csv')
test_data = data['text']
doc_id = data['doc_id']
page_id = data['page_id']

def TOC(text):
    return 'content' in text

def new_doc():
    if i==0:
        return False
    elif doc_id[i] != doc_id[i-1]:
        return True

i=0

while i < len(test_data):
    stop=0
    while stop == 0 and not new_doc():
        if TOC(test_data[i]):
            print('toc')
            stop=1
        else:
            print(doc_id[i],test_data[i])
        i+=1
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
a = df[df.page_id<5]
def tex(x):
    try:
        if (x.any()):
            i = x.index[x.str.contains('Table')][0]      
    except IndexError :
            i = x.index[-1]+1          
    return i
a[a.index<a.groupby('doc_id')['text'].transform(tex)]['text'].to_list()
```

**Output**

```
['A0', 'A1', 'B1', 'A3']
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate through whole document

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('book2.csv')[['page_id', 'doc_id', 'text']]
curr_doc_id = -1
before_toc = False
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    if curr_doc_id < row.doc_id:
        curr_doc_id = row.doc_id
        before_toc = True
    if row.text == "Table of Contents":
        before_toc = False
    if before_toc and row.page_id < 5:
        print(row)
```

*code wasn't tested